# Different background for different script in same file using PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, editorconfig

I am new **PhpStorm** user. I can't find the option where I see different background color preview for different script in a file. Like the following image of Netbeans IDE.

Please help me to find out the configuration in **PhpStorm**

[image]

Comment: Me too need a answer of this

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is so to externalize in a `js` file out of the `html` one.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently possible, please vote for [IDEABKL-6375](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6375) and linked tickets